# Can older wallpapers be used in newer releases?

Tags: desktop-background

is there a way to get the old wallpaper (for instance from 13.10(?  I really liked one of them and 14.04 does not have it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, download the wallpaper from google pictures and add it to your pictures map. From appearances you can add it as a wallpaper.

**13.10**

- [Default wallpaper](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/09/ubuntu-13-10-default-wallpaper-revealed).

[image]

- [18 wallpapers that won the contest](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/08/ubuntu-13-10-winning-wallpapers-revealed).

[image]

And in case anyone wonders:

**13.04**

- [Default wallpaper](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/ubuntu-13-04-default-wallpaper-revealed)
- [13 wallpapers that won the contest](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/ubuntu-13-04-winning-wallpapers-announced)

**12.04**

- [Default wallpaper](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/ubuntu-12-04-default-wallpaper-revealed/)
- [15 wallpapers that won the contest](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/15-new-wallpapers-land-in-ubuntu-12-04)

In case the links disappear you can also download all of the from the [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/ubuntu-wallpapers) page.